# How to make custom fragments

Tags: android

I am creating a quiz app in which I am storing questions in Arraylist but now I have to display them using fragments but I am not able to figure out how to display questions stored in arraylist in fragment below is the code

this is the database code

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("What is JP?","Jalur Pesawat", "Jack sParrow", "Jasa Programmer", "Jasa Programmer");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("where the JP place?", "Monas, Jakarta", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bantul", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bandul", "Gelondong, Bangun Tapan, bantul");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("who is CEO of the JP?","Usman and Jack", "Jack and Rully","Rully and Usman", "Rully and Usman" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("what do you know about JP?", "JP is programmer home", "JP also realigy home", "all answer is true","all answer is true");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("what do you learn in JP?","Realigy","Programming","all answer is true","all answer is true");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

and this is the code of main activity in which I should make change

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{


    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging()
    {
        List<Fragment> fragments =new Vector<Fragment>();

         mPagerAdapter= new com.example.android.viewpager4.PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
         ViewPager pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
         pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

and this is the xml layout in which I have to display question with radio button as options

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity" 
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my pageadapter code

```
package com.example.android.viewpager4;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Vikas on 4/27/2016.
 */
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
   private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the code for the PagerAdapter. Also, I would recommend passing the list of Question objects to that. In the `getItem` method is where you initialize a Fragment for that Question

Comment: I have uploaded that page Adapter code can you please tell me what changes I should do I am new to android

Comment: Well, you seem to understand the `List<Fragment>` concept. The PagerAdapter does need some list and the `getItem` method there does need to return a Fragment. So do you have a class that extends `Fragment`? You can refer here on best practices that I recommend for making passing data into a Fragment  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: I will try it and try to make a solution out of it  thanks man if I get another problem then please help me again thanks in advance

Comment: Till now I have not made any class that extends fragment

Comment: Please tell me what to do I have to complete it by tomorrow

Comment: Well, you might want to define a Fragment, then.  For example,  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: hey please help once more I have implemented the code according to the tutorial but I am getting only 1 question in every fragment this is link \

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945663/getting-error-in-the-app-after-making-custom-fragments

Answer (score 0):

I had to do pass an array to a fragment in my app Also. I used Gson to do it easily.

In your activity with the array list.

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<YOUR_ARRAY_TYPE>>() {}.getType();
        String json = gson.toJson(ARRAY_LIST,type);
        args.putString("key",json);
        NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment();
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Now in your receiving fragment:

```
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<YOUR_ARRAY_TYPE>>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = bundle.getString("key");
    List<YOUR_ARRAY_TYPE> linkers = gson.fromJson(json,type);
```